# Array of pointer not giving proper output as it suppose?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Hi i have array of two pointers int *p[2] and i am trying to store 3 address of integer lets take &i,&j,&k as below code At *p[0]

i am getting garbage why here garbage ?it should be at p[2]? At *p[1] i am getting value it is ok but At *p[2] i am getting value here i should get garbage?

```
     #include<stdio.h> 
     int main()       
     { 
        int i=10,j=20,k=30;  

        int *p[2];                 // here p is array of 2 pointers   
        p[0]=&i;                   // but here i am storing   
        p[1]=&j;                   // 3 address of variable i,j,k 
        p[2]=&k; 

        printf("p[0]=%d\n",*p[0]); // why garbage here ?         
        printf("p[1]=%d\n",*p[1]); // here 20 
        printf("p[2]=%d\n",*p[2]); // here 30 why here ? 
     }
```

Comment: Please re-indent your code.

Comment: You're trying to put 3 elements in a 2-element array. Literally *anything* could happen.

Comment: How do you tell a "value" from a "garbage"? What makes you think that `30` is not your garbage? Did you expect garbage values to be printed in different color? Or something else?

Comment: @AndreyT because if i repalce 30 with 40 or any number then 40 is printed

Comment: @user3871332: Well, "garbage" in garbage output does not normally come from a random number generator. It comes from reading memory. In your case it comes from reading some unpredictable memory location. And as you probably already guessed, in your case that "unpredictable memory location" just happened to coincide with the location of your `k` variable. It just so happened by accident. So, the garbage that you see just happened to originate from `k`. That does not make it less of a garbage.

Comment: @user3871332: In your question you state that you "store 3 address of integer" in `p`. Where is it in your code? I don't see it. In your code you store only 2 addresses in `p`. Also, why do you claim that `*p[0]` prints garbage?? That is false, it does not print garbage. In other words, your question directly contradicts your code. Bring them in sync. At this time, in its current form, the question just makes no sense.

Comment: @AndreyT please compile and see u will find it

Comment: @user3871332: I already did that. The behavior you describe is not reproducible, as you have been told already. `*p[0]` reliably outputs `10`, as it should. An attempt to access `*p[2]` simply crashes the program.

Comment: compile it now *p[2]=&k  was mistakely commented

Comment: Well, now there's only one answer: your code exhibits *undefined behavior*. That's all there is to it. There's no other answer to any "why" questions. Your code's behavior is random and unpredictable. That's all. Don't attempt to perform out-of-bounds array access.

Comment: @AndreyT its ok i agree but why it is effecting index 0 ?why *p[0] is changed to garbage

Comment: @user3871332 again, it's undefined behavior. It doesn't need to be explained. But, if I had to guess, it's because of how the locals are arranged on the stack - I bet if you were to print both `&i` and `&p[2]`, you'd get the same address.

Comment: Exactly, when wrote something into the non-existing `p[2]`, you actually destroyed the value of `i`. You can print `i` and you will see that `i` now contains the same garbage as you see through `*p[0]`.

Comment: @AndreyT thanks for replying but please can you say why it is destroyed?

Comment: @user3871332: Because `p` and `i` are located next to each other in memory. When you get out of bounds of `p` with your `p[2]`, you cross the boundary of `p`'s memory area and intrude into the memory area that belongs to `i`. Any attempts to modify `p[2]` actually modify memory that belongs to `i`.

Answer (score 5):

> `printf("p[2]=%d\n",*p[2]);` // here 30 why here ?

Because `p` has two elements, not three. You can access elements 0 and 1, but accessing 2 is undefined behavior. Any number can be printed, or your program could crash when you invoke undefined behavior.

> I am getting value here i should get garbage?

30 is as good a garbage value as any other number.

**EDIT (in response to an edit of the question) When you assign `p[2] = &k` you write to a location that is not allocated to your program. However, if the write operation completes without a crash, the new value would stay in memory.

Since the memory to which you wrote an address of `k` does not belong to your program, the system may write a new value into it. However, it wouldn't do it with 100% certainty: it may not write a new value into that memory at all. This is precisely what appears to be happening in your case: the value of `&k` written into `p[2]` illegally "survives" past two invocations of `printf`, producing `30` as the result.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight 30 is value i assign if i repalce with other number then it get printed its not garbage

Comment: @user3871332 Take a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/RbwDu3), it makes `*p[2]` print a different value. The code is self-explanatory as to why this happens (note the final `printf`).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok thanks just last dout   p[0]=&k;           
                           p[1]=&k;                   
                            p[2]=&k;  when i store all only k then i get *p[o] ,*p[1],*p[2] as garbage why?

Comment: @user3871332 I get all 30-s when I assign `&k` to all ([demo](http://ideone.com/w2j8yn)).

Answer (score 0):

u are using   `int *p[2]`, which is an array of size 2. only `p[0]` and `p[1]` are valid. remember the index of an array in c++ starts with 0 not 1. using `p[2]` would end up with something strange.

Answer (score 0):

you are having array of two pointers `int *p[2]`. But you are trying to print the next element using pointer-

```
printf("p[2]=%d\n",*p[2]);
```

It results in undefined behavior. Anything can happen. But you are getting `30` some times you may get garbage values.

For your program i am getting-

```
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string# ./a.out 
p[0]=10
p[1]=20
p[2]=-13543595 // note this value. Undefined Behaviour
root@ubuntu:~/c/array/string#
```

Comment: no i am not getting rather it is making 0 index garbage value plz compile and try once

Comment: @user3871332 Note the output above!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need

```
int *p[3].
```

secondly since you used

```
int *p[2]
```

p[2] wasn't kept aside for this array. so what was there at p[2]? in my case it was variable k.
mine was 64 bit system with 64 bit pointers.
my output

```
p[0]=10 
p[1]=20 
p[2]=32767
```

and look at the gdb dump especially the addresses of k and p[2]

```
(gdb) p p[0]
$7 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe02c
(gdb) p p[1]
$8 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe028
(gdb) p p[2]
$9 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe024
(gdb) p &i
$10 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe02c
(gdb) p &j
$11 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe028
(gdb) p &k
$12 = (int *) 0x7fffffffe024
(gdb) p &p
$14 = (int *(*)[2]) 0x7fffffffe010
(gdb) x/32 0x7fffffffe010
0x7fffffffe010: -8148   32767   -8152   32767
0x7fffffffe020: -8156   32767   20  10
```

in your case it must have been the address of i.